# Is this recursive function impossible to be iterative?

Tags: c++, loops, recursion, iteration

I tried to think a bit to make this function iterative. It seemed possible, but I currently cannot find a way to do so. So is it even possible to prove that this function cannot be iterative in whatever way? What I mean by iterative is not using recursive function calls at all.

// I love this new `auto` keyword.

```
void every_permutation(const std::vector<int>& v, std::vector<std::vector<int>>& vs) {
    if (v.size() == 1) {
        vs.push_back(v);
        return;
    }
    for (auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i) {
        std::vector<int> v_2;
        for (auto j = v.begin(); j != v.end(); ++j) {
            if (j != i) {
                v_2.push_back(*j);
            }
        }
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> vs_2;
        every_permutation(v_2, vs_2);
        for (auto j = vs_2.begin(); j != vs_2.end(); ++j) {
            j->push_back(*i);
        }
        vs.insert(vs.end(), vs_2.begin(), vs_2.end());
    }
}
```

Comment: Theoretically all recursive algorithms can be transformed into iterative algorithms with a stack.

Comment: A description of the algorithm would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function certainly can be iterative. In fact, there's a function in the standard library that does it iteratively: `std::next_permutation`. You could use it like so:

```
                                     // v-- note: v is a copy here
void every_permutation(std::vector<int> v, std::vector<std::vector<int>>& vs) {
  // because we need to start with a sorted vector to get all permutations.
  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());

  do {
    vs.push_back(v);
  } while(std::next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));
}
```

Of course, this snippet does not tell you how `std::next_permutation` does it, but happily there is a possible implementation described [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation).

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're asking is whether this recursive function is **tail recursive**. Tail recursive functions can be easily rewritten as loops and don't require a stack to keep track of multiple frames of local variables. This function is **not** tail recursive; indeed, any recursive function that might call itself more than once per iteration cannot possibly be tail recursive.

Recursive functions that are not tail recursive can still be written iteratively, but you need some sort of stack in order to keep track of the state of the computation so you can go back to it after solving a nested subproblem. The amount of space used will be at least proportional to the nesting depth.

Of course, a function that is not tail recursive can sometimes be rewritten so that it is tail recursive. In some cases you need to completely change the algorithm used in order to accomplish this.